# Suggestions on how to have an automated job check for newer versions of an AWS resource and update it. The IAC used is Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, gitlab, terraform, gitlab-ci

Before I start to create this from scratch I am wondering if there are existing tools, plugins or code that already exist to achieve my automated updating goal.

We already have IAC using Terraform to bring up and maintain our AWS MSK clusters - this is stored in a Gitlab project.

We have GitLab jobs that let us deploy and update MSK clusters that use the Terraform. We run these jobs manually now when we make a change in the project that holds the Terraform.

What we would like to do is have a GitLab job that automatically runs every day (or once a week) that checks to see if there is a minor version update or patch update for the MKS cluster and if so then it automatically updates the Terraform IAC with the new version and runs a job to update the AWS MSK cluster to that new version.

So right now we have an MSK cluster at version 2.7.0

The scenario would be -

1 - Some kind of check is run (I assume I would create a script that runs AWS cli commands) to see if there is a newer version of AWS MSK than what we have.

2 - It finds out that version 2.7.1 is available.

3 - The TF code stored in our Gitlab project that holds the version is updated to now be 2.7.1 (right now we store the version in a tf file but I assume if we need to we can store it in a variable - I think we would prefer keeping it in a file if possible).

4 - A pipeline/job is automatically kicked off that now applies Terraform with the change - the change being that the MSK version is updated.

So does anything exist to help a process like this work or are there any suggestions out there on the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I cant think of a way to better your solution due to a lack of inside out monitoring features in aws-cli.
Assuming that you are using [best practices](https://spacelift.io/blog/terraform-best-practices) for terraform, I can't see an improvement for 1-3.

For step 4. If your business use case is not impacted by small margins, the automatic update from aws-cli should do the trick.

For critical use cases where there is no room for latency or delays, I would recommend proceeding with a well formed update strategy.